# Include same JSP file twice in another JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

This is a pretty simple JSP problem that, for some reason, I can't find an answer for.

I want to include the same JSP file twice within another JSP file. The very simplified version of `main.jsp` is:

```
<html>
<%@ include file="feed.jsp" %> 
<%@ include file="feed.jsp" %>
</html>
```

The very simplified version of `feed.jsp` is:

```
<html>
${myFeed}
</html>
```

The servlet sends two request attributes: myFeed1 and myFeed2:

```
request.setAttribute("myFeed1", myFeed1);
request.setAttribute("myFeed2", myFeed2);
```

What I want to happen is have the value of myFeed1 appear in the first included JSP and the value of myFeed2 appear in the second included JSP.

I want to use JSP directives not actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create variable myFeed using c:set with myFeed1 value before first include and override it with myFeed2 before second include:

```
<c:set var="myFeed" values="${myFeed1} />
<%@ include file="feed.jsp" %>
<c:set var="myFeed" values="${myFeed2} />
<%@ include file="feed.jsp" %>
```

Or you can use tags and pass attributes to them.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Select Different Value like

```
<html>
<CCS var="myFeed" values="${myFeed1} />
<%@ include file="index.jsp" %> 
<CCS var="myFeed" values="${myFeed2} />
<%@ include file="index.jsp" %>
</html>
```

Hope it will work